# symfony wrong index and auto redirect to xampp webpage

Tags: symfony1, xampp, redirect

I installed xampp and it works great with my symfony. I even made few excercises on projects.
However I cannot setup my latest project which was coppied from another PC.

How it looks: well the site opening in

http://localhost/ppz/chujwiecotobedzie/web/frontend_dev.php

looks good, but when i make

symfony cc

(in case) and then open in

http://localhost/ppz/chujwiecotobedzie/web/

the page is redirecting to xampp homepage.

I use symfony 1.4
There are frontend and backend folders. I was working only in frontend folder.
I think that any file can make this mess but i dont know.
Please help.

xamp-apache:

```
#
# Virtual Hosts
#
# If you want to maintain multiple domains/hostnames on your
# machine you can setup VirtualHost containers for them. Most configurations
# use only name-based virtual hosts so the server doesn't need to worry about
# IP addresses. This is indicated by the asterisks in the directives below.
#
# Please see the documentation at 
# <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/>
# for further details before you try to setup virtual hosts.
#
# You may use the command line option '-S' to verify your virtual host
# configuration.

#
# Use name-based virtual hosting.
#
##NameVirtualHost *:80

#
# VirtualHost example:
# Almost any Apache directive may go into a VirtualHost container.
# The first VirtualHost section is used for all requests that do not
# match a ServerName or ServerAlias in any <VirtualHost> block.
#
##<VirtualHost *:80>
    ##ServerAdmin postmaster@dummy-host.localhost
    ##DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/dummy-host.localhost"
    ##ServerName dummy-host.localhost
    ##ServerAlias www.dummy-host.localhost
    ##ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host.localhost-error.log"
    ##CustomLog "logs/dummy-host.localhost-access.log" combined
##</VirtualHost>

##<VirtualHost *:80>
    ##ServerAdmin postmaster@dummy-host2.localhost
    ##DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/dummy-host2.localhost"
    ##ServerName dummy-host2.localhost
    ##ServerAlias www.dummy-host2.localhost
    ##ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host2.localhost-error.log"
    ##CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.localhost-access.log" combined
##</VirtualHost>
```

windows hosts:

```
# Copyright (c) 1993-2009 Microsoft Corp.
#
# This is a sample HOSTS file used by Microsoft TCP/IP for Windows.
#
# This file contains the mappings of IP addresses to host names. Each
# entry should be kept on an individual line. The IP address should
# be placed in the first column followed by the corresponding host name.
# The IP address and the host name should be separated by at least one
# space.
#
# Additionally, comments (such as these) may be inserted on individual
# lines or following the machine name denoted by a '#' symbol.
#
# For example:
#
#      102.54.94.97     rhino.acme.com          # source server
#       38.25.63.10     x.acme.com              # x client host

# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost

127.0.0.1 localhost
```

I am working with netbeans 7 with installed plugins: php + symfony

---

### edit1: i changed path from myproject to real my path chu...

[image][image]

In front page opened by frontend_dev i can see text from indexSuccess:
[image]

But if i click any link it shows:
[image]

---

how i solved:
1 chnaged this directory to shorter and put in another. C:\www

2 in this folder i put all files from project: apps, cache, etc (if you dont have file 'symfony' you ought make it, this way symfony will know this is symfony directory project)

3 c:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts i put only one sign: 127.0.0.1 localhost.tld

4 in apache: C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\ httpd vhost i put: 
NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
 ServerName localhost.tld
 DocumentRoot "C:\www\web"
 DirectoryIndex index.php
 <Directory "C:\www\web">
 AllowOverride All
 Allow from All
 </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

5 in netbeans> properities of my project > run configuration > project url > i wrote: http://localhost.ltd/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me like there is a mix up regarding the folders.

frontend_dev.php should be inside of the web/ directory

if localhost/myproject/project1/frontend_dev.php is working, then the production version should be accessible at:

localhost/myproject/project1/index.php

Comment: in path: http://localhost/ppz/chujwiecotobedzie/ it shows me source ( all files). If i put /index.php it says object not found because index is in web folder, right?

Comment: http://localhost/ppz/chujwiecotobedzie/web/frontend_dev.php works perfect, however after i click any link (for example i implemented action executeBut and wrote text in butSuccess : test) the page says 404 object not found. In action executeIndex which is shown in frontpage i can see "test" text. What is wrong?

Comment: @Michal Mokrzycki could you do another edit to show the code you're using to display the link that isn't working?

Comment: i found error, i had to configure vhost in apache with specific virtualhost: